How to export JSON compilation commands using CMake with the Visual Studio 17 2022 generator?
I'm currently using CMake with the Visual Studio 17 2022 generator, and I need to export the JSON compilation database (compile_commands.json) for use with tools like clangd. I tried setting the CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS option, but it doesn't seem to work with the Visual Studio generator.
According to the CMake documentation, this option is implemented only by Makefile Generators and Ninja Generators and is ignored on other generators, including Visual Studio. This seems to imply that it's not possible to generate compile_commands.json directly when using the Visual Studio generator.
Is there a workaround or alternative method to generate the JSON compilation commands when using the Visual Studio 17 2022 generator?
I added CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS to my CMakeLists.txt, expecting it to generate compile_commands.json with the Visual Studio 17 2022 generator, but it didn’t work. I found out this option only works with Makefile and Ninja generators. I’m looking for a way to export the JSON compilation commands using the Visual Studio generator.

This question is similar to: Generate clang compilation database for a Visual Studio project. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note this answer of mine which generates compile_commands.json on Windows without MinGW / make installation.
